# Protecting office/excel files from theft, changing MS office excel's auto recovery path is not working, whats the issue?

Tags: microsoft-excel, encryption, bitlocker, efs

I'm changing excel 19's autorecover file location on windows 10 on excel/options/save to a folder on bitlocker encrypted partition. When editing file without saving, it creates a file with .xar extension on new path but at the same time creates auto recovery files on default location "User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel" as it normally does by default. After changing auto recover path, it's supposed to create all those temporary recovery files on new location, am i missing something? Appreciate insights thanks.

Btw, i can encrypt whole os partition where office keep autorecover files, but dont want to do that for various reasons like performance impact. Encrypting only recovery files/folders on os partition would be ok but i think there is not a good and free way to do it on windows 10/11. Afaik, efs is not an option as it doesnt password protect files and it doesnt protect files if user login is hacked.

Update: Looks like efs encryption can be used on windows to protect folders/files with a cert. It can be used to protect auto recovery files in case machine is compromised. Well, its valid unless windows account login is compromised. Only the user account who created efs files (with same account password used during encryption) can access the files. Actually any user can access the files if own the right efs cert which is another story. So basically efs can be a workaround to protect office recovery files without encrypting entire partition/drive with a tool like bitlocker. Yet, it would be nice to be able to change office's recovery file location. There is an option for that on excel but its not working for some reason..

Comment: Where did you change this location so I can attempt to recreate this behavior?

Comment: @Ramhound excel/options/save

Comment: In same Save section, change "Server drafts location".

Comment: You have things backwards.  If the machine is compromised, EFS would encrypt your files, which would prevent a malicious party from simply resetting the account's password.  Granted, BitLocker would prevent somebody from copying the entire HDD, and taking their time accessing your files. I would be shocked if there was an measureable performance impact with BitLocker protection.

Comment: Worth pointing out that neither EFS or BItLocker is designed to protect from digital theft.  Disabling auto recovery entirely, preventing auto save, and only allowing documents to be saved in specific location are helpful to combat the theft of a document.  There are third-party tools that exist also. If you copy a file, from a BItLocker protected volume that is mounted and unlocked, to a volume that isn't protected the copy of the file won't be encrypted.

Comment: @Ramhound ok so if i encrypt excel auto recovery files with built in efs, then when machine compromised and user account password  has been reset, efs files wont be accessible, right? Can hacker/thief get efs certificates from machine to access files? Those certificates are protected with password i guess so without pw they cant be used.     



Even if my user account pw has been changed, i can still access  efs encrypted files as long as i ve got the cert and know the cert pw, right?

Comment: btw, main problem that excel still put recovery files to default location despite  changing the location on options, still remains and dont know if this is a bug or what.. I really like excel, who doesnt, one of the most useful software ever made. For security, ability to change recovery file location is important, also auto saving feature instead of recovery file would be another nice option to have.

Comment: What exact CPU do you have? Its AES-NI support is what determines whether BitLocker will have a performance impact or not.